# Why is Star Wars named Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, george-lucas

What was the reason to call *Star Wars* actually *Star Wars*?

I am not a native English speaker and in the first years as a child/teenager I only heard/spoke about the german translated movie titles:

> Krieg der Sterne

what literally translated to English should be

> War of (the) stars.

But what should a war between stars emphasize?

Is Star Wars just a good sounding synonym for epic space battles or does it have a deeper meaning? And did George Lucas invented the name?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/102169/20774