# Were there EU prequels before canon?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, behind-the-scenes

*The Phantom Menace*, starting the Canon prequels, was released in 1999.

Back then, I came across an old SF magazine that described the Extended Universe sequels to the Original Trilogy. Prequels were not mentioned, the article was incomplete (to be continued in the next issue of the magazine).

I wonder if there were **EU prequel** novels or comic books **before the Canon prequels** came into existence. How much do they contradict the canon?

PS. I am aware of the non-canon alternative prequel trilogy by David Gremillion (*Awakening - Horizons - Hunted*), but this was written after the canon prequels, as an alternative, and is not officially canon at all (not EU, considered fan fiction), so this does not count.

Comment: [Computer says no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars_books#Star_Wars:_Legends) although there were some Han Solo ones from 10 BBY (22 years after TPM)

Comment: An answer to this question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/78794/why-was-the-single-war-between-the-republic-and-the-cis-called-the-clone-wars mentions novels that describe the fall of the Republic as it was conceived before the prequel trilogy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are some media from the era prior to the original trilogy, published before *The Phantom Menace*. I went through the [list of Legends media on Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_Legends_media) and collected the titles of the novels, young readers books, and comics set earlier than 0 BBY and published prior to 1999.

**1979**

- [Han Solo at Stars' End](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_Solo_at_Stars%27_End), 2–1 BBY
- [Han Solo's Revenge](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_Solo%27s_Revenge), 2–1 BBY

**1980**

- [Han Solo and the Lost Legacy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Han_Solo_and_the_Lost_Legacy), 2–1 BBY

**1983**

- [Lando Calrissian and the Mindharp of Sharu](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lando_Calrissian_and_the_Mindharp_of_Sharu), 4 BBY
- [Lando Calrissian and the Flamewind of Oseon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lando_Calrissian_and_the_Flamewind_of_Oseon), 3 BBY
- [Lando Calrissian and the Starcave of ThonBoka](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lando_Calrissian_and_the_Starcave_of_ThonBoka), 3–2.5 BBY

**1985**

- [The Lost Prince: A Droid Adventure](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lost_Prince:_A_Droid_Adventure), 15 BBY

**1986**

- [The White Witch: A Droid Adventure](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_White_Witch:_A_Droid_Adventure), 15 BBY
- [The Pirates of Tarnoonga: A Droid Adventure](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Pirates_of_Tarnoonga:_A_Droid_Adventure), 15 BBY
- [Escape from the Monster Ship: A Droid Adventure](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Escape_from_the_Monster_Ship:_A_Droid_Adventure), 15 BBY
- [Star Wars Droids](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Droids_(Marvel)), 10 BBY

**1987**

- [The White Witch](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_White_Witch_(book)), 15 BBY
- [Escape Into Terror](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Escape_Into_Terror_(book)), 15 BBY
- [The Trigon Unleashed](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Trigon_Unleashed_(book)), 15 BBY
- [A Race to the Finish](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_Race_to_the_Finish_(book)), 15 BBY

**1993**

- [Tales of the Jedi: Ulic Qel-Droma and the Beast Wars of Onderon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tales_of_the_Jedi:_Ulic_Qel-Droma_and_the_Beast_Wars_of_Onderon), 4000 BBY
- [Tales of the Jedi: The Saga of Nomi Sunrider](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tales_of_the_Jedi:_The_Saga_of_Nomi_Sunrider), 3999 BBY

**1994**

- [Droids: The Kalarba Adventures](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Droids:_The_Kalarba_Adventures), 5.5 BBY
- [Tales of the Jedi: Dark Lords of the Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tales_of_the_Jedi:_Dark_Lords_of_the_Sith), 3997 BBY
- [Droids: Artoo's Day Out](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Droids:_Artoo%27s_Day_Out), 5.5 BBY

**1995**

- [Droids: Special](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Droids_Special), 5.5 BBY
- [Jabba the Hutt: The Gaar Suppoon Hit](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jabba_the_Hutt:_The_Gaar_Suppoon_Hit), 5 BBY
- [Jabba the Hutt: The Hunger of Princess Nampi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jabba_the_Hutt:_The_Hunger_of_Princess_Nampi), 5 BBY
- [Droids: Rebellion](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Droids:_Rebellion), 5.5 BBY
- [Star Wars: Tales of the Jedi—The Sith War](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Tales_of_the_Jedi%E2%80%94The_Sith_War), 3996–3994 BBY
- [Jabba the Hutt: The Dynasty Trap](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jabba_the_Hutt:_The_Dynasty_Trap), 5 BBY
- [Droids: Season of Revolt](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Droids:_Season_of_Revolt), 5.5 BBY

**1996**

- [Jabba the Hutt: Betrayal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jabba_the_Hutt:_Betrayal), 5 BBY
- [Tales of the Jedi: The Golden Age of the Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tales_of_the_Jedi:_The_Golden_Age_of_the_Sith), 5000 BBY
- [This Crumb for Hire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/This_Crumb_for_Hire), 2 BBY

**1997**

- [Dark Forces: Soldier for the Empire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Forces:_Soldier_for_the_Empire), 1 BBY
- [The Paradise Snare](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Paradise_Snare), c. 10 BBY
- [Tales of the Jedi: The Fall of the Sith Empire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Tales_of_the_Jedi_%E2%80%94_The_Fall_of_the_Sith_Empire), 5000 BBY
- [The Hutt Gambit](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Hutt_Gambit), c. 5–4 BBY
- [Droids: The Protocol Offensive](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Droids:_The_Protocol_Offensive), 5.5 BBY

**1998**

- [Rebel Dawn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rebel_Dawn), c. 2–0 BBY
- [Tales of the Jedi: Redemption](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tales_of_the_Jedi:_Redemption), 3986 BBY
- [Prelude to Rebellion](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Republic:_Prelude_to_Rebellion), 32.5 BBY

**1999**

- [Boba Fett: Enemy of the Empire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boba_Fett:_Enemy_of_the_Empire), 3 BBY
- [Republic: Vow of Justice](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Republic:_Vow_of_Justice), 67 BBY
- [Jedi Apprentice: The Rising Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Apprentice:_The_Rising_Force), 44 BBY
- [Jedi Apprentice: The Dark Rival](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Apprentice:_The_Dark_Rival), 44 BBY

Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with any of these books, so I cannot tell if any of the stories has had an influence on the current Canon. But maybe I'll later check out one or two of the most interesting titles...

Comment: Splinter of the Mind’s Eye (1978) is another one, set between Star Wars & Empire https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splinter_of_the_Mind's_Eye

Comment: @Nick Splinter of the Mind's Eye was the first EU book, but it was not a prequel, since it came out before *Empire*.

Comment: The 15 BBY date is listed on numerous Web sites, but it is also clearly wrong for the series of *Droids* stories involving Mungo Baobab, such as *Escape from the Monster Ship: A Droid Adventure*.  The original *Droids* cartoon versions of the stories referred to the "new" emperor who had replaced the killed in *Return of the Jedi.*  On the other hand, some of the other *Droids* stories clearly do take place before *A New Hope.*